# ternary operation in blazor, convert a if-else statement into just one statement

Tags: c#, blazor

I have the following code in a page.razor:

```
                    @if (i==1)
                    {
                        <MudTimelineItem  Color="Color.Primary" Size="Size.Medium" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
                            <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Success">@matrix.UserName</MudAlert>
                        </MudTimelineItem>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <MudTimelineItem   Variant="Variant.Outlined">
                            <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Success">@matrix.UserName</MudAlert>
                        </MudTimelineItem>
                    }
```

The only thing that changes is the color and size parameters, rest remains the same, Instead of using if-else statement can this be written in just one line using ternary operators or any other with which blazor supports?

Answer (score 2):

Blazor should not render attribute if it's value is `null` or `false` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#conditional-html-element-attributes)). Try something like:

```
<MudTimelineItem Color="@(i == 1 ? Color.Primary : null)" Size="@(i == 1 ? Size.Medium : null)" Variant="Variant.Outlined">
    <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Success">@matrix.UserName</MudAlert>
</MudTimelineItem>
```

Comment: Color="@(i == 1 ? Color.Primary : null)" the null didnot work. i had replace with Color.Default, it expects some value.   Is it possible to render the attribute Color only if i=1 and skip it if it is i=0

Comment: @Venkat what is `Color`? Is it enum or struct?

Comment: it is enum...... If there is a way to avoid the attribute color altogether if i=0 it would be perfect.

Comment: The defaults should be `<MudTimelineItem Color="@(i == 1 ? Color.Primary : Color.Default)" Size="@(i == 1 ? Size.Medium : Size.Small)" Variant="Variant.Outlined">`  And no you either use your `If... else` or the above.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis just use nullable enums: `i == 1 ? Color.Primary : (Color?) null)`

Comment: `MudTimelineItem` is a MudBlazor library component (https://www.mudblazor.com/api/timelineitem#properties) declared like this: `public Color Color { get; set; } = Color.Default;`  I see a default but no `Nullable`!  That's why `Color="@(i == 1 ? Color.Primary : null)"` didn't work.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis then just set it to default.

Comment: @GuruStron.  [Polite]  ???? How do we know the default value set in the component is the default (0) value for the Enum.  I was just setting the values to the defaults declared in the component.  With the one liner you've got to set them to something.  A classic case of set the value so you know what you're getting!  If someone at MudBlazor suddenly decided to change the 0 value to Danger then ....